# how to create user profile pages and display them based on users roles

Tags: plugins, users, user-roles, profiles

Example: I have a website with 3 different user roles (amongst others):
*developers
*designers
*contributors

I would like to have profile pages for users and would like to be able to display users on pages based (filtered) by their role.
Hope this is clear. I have researched quite a few membership plugins and found that they are just bloated with features and ended up with TMI and no answers/solutions, so if you can help I would appreciate it.
Do you know of any plugins suitable of doing that?

Thanx in advance

Comment: What do you want on the profile pages? Would a normal author page do? You could put conditional sections in the author page template based on the user's role.

Comment: @Rup Hmmm... What i want to appear is a featured image, a description and some links along with the created content. I also want to have archive(?) pages of authors based on their role.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get you started. This creates a shortcode [alldevelopers] that displays a list of all developers. Pretty basic but can be heavily extended and duplicted. (Not tested)

```
add_shortcode( 'alldevelopers', 'show_all_developers' );
function show_all_developers(){
   $users = get_users( [ 'role__in' => [ 'developers' ] ] );
      foreach ( $users as $user ) {
         echo $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name . '<br>';
      }
}
```

Comment: After some exhausting research I think I will give the toolset plugin a try, thanx anyway